# Angular 6 add external remote third party javascript file using link url in angular.json file

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I want to include the Google Maps API in my Angular 6 project, so when I include the given link in the documentation: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap to my project index.html page (with the generated api key of course), it works pretty good. But I am wondering if there isn't a better place to put that javascript file so that webpack can process it and bundle it with the vendors file ?

I tried in the angular.json file to put the url in the `projects > projectName > architect > build > options > scripts and assets` but both raised an error because angular was looking for a local path... Thus not recognizing an http url. Is it possible to include external script files in the angular cli config json  file ?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51205537/how-to-include-external-js-file-to-angular5

Comment: I am looking for embedding external scripts