# How to include external JS file to angular5?

Tags: angular, typescript, package.json

I am new to angular and started learning angular5 from this [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial) .

I am converting normal HTML template to Angular 5 version now I am facing difficulties when adding **external JS file to angular 5** project.

Can anyone help me to add external js file to angular5 project ?

Here is my updated angular.json file. still not working for me.

```js
/*angular.json*/
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "minimus-master": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/minimus-master",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/vendors/jquery/jquery.min.js",
              "src/assets/vendors/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.js",
              "src/assets/vendors/isotope-layout/isotope.pkgd.js",
              "src/assets/vendors/jquery-one-page/jquery.nav.min.js",
              "src/assets/vendors/jquery.easing/jquery.easing.min.js",
              "src/assets/vendors/jquery.matchHeight/jquery.matchHeight.min.js",
              "src/assets/vendors/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js",
              "src/assets/vendors/masonry-layout/masonry.pkgd.js",
              "src/assets/vendors/jquery.waypoints/jquery.waypoints.min.js",
              "src/assets/vendors/swiper/swiper.jquery.js",
              "src/assets/vendors/menu/menu.js",
              "src/assets/vendors/typed/typed.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/main.js"            
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "minimus-master:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "minimus-master:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "minimus-master:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "minimus-master-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "minimus-master:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "minimus-master:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "minimus-master"
}
```

Comment: angularjs and angular are two very different things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add Javascript files to the global scope via the `scripts`
option inside your project's build target options in `angular.json`.
These will be loaded exactly as if you had added them in a `<script>`
tag inside index.html.

```
<script src="path to your js file"></script>
```

or

You can specify the **global scripts** to be included in the build , In your angular project's **angular.json file scripts array**

(angular-cli.json file if your angular version is < 6.0).

```
{
  "scripts": [
    // path to your js file
  ]
}
```

Refer [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli) article for more info.

Comment: I updated my angular.json file still not working for me.

Comment: it's working for me but showing "jquery.easing.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"

Comment: how are you loading the js file ? have you already download the js file ?

Comment: yes I already downloaded files and added in /src/assets folder.
you can see my updated angular.json file above

Comment: Your path should be chnaged like this.
`"./assets/vendors/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.js",`

Comment: I added "src/assets/vendors/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.js", this way it's working but jquery or $ not defined error shows

Comment: How did you import jQuery in to ts files?

Comment: I added via angular.json file I updated file please check above.

Comment: No I mean how are you using jQuery in the application. (In components)

Comment: I am not using any jquery in component I am just including jquery in angular.json file. All custom code is written in main.js file

Comment: Better to ask a new question regarding that. Your original question was
**How to include external JS file to angular5?**. I've answered that.

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51209209/angularjs5-custom-javascript-file-not-working

Answer (score 0):

You would edit your `angular-cli.json`'s script section and add the file

```
"scripts": [
    "<path to your js file>",
]
```