# Angular 5 externnal javascript file not working

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and started learning angular5 from this [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial).

I am converting normal HTML template to Angular5 version now I am facing difficulties when adding **external JS files to angular5 project**.

I included Javascript files in angular project in angular.json file but my javascript files seems not working.

Can anyone help in that ?
Am I going in right way by writing custom jquery code on main.js file ?

I am saying now working in terms of jQuery code see example code below.

```js
/**
   * Typing effect Not working
   */
jQuery('.typing__module').each(function (index) {
 var self = jQuery(this),
      _wrapper = jQuery('.typed', self)[0],
      optData = eval('(' + self.attr('data-options') + ')'),
      optDefault = {
  stringsElement: self.find('.typed-strings')[0],
  typeSpeed: 50,
  backSpeed: 500,
  fadeOut: true,
  loop: true
 },
      options = jQuery.extend(optDefault, optData);
 var typed = new Typed(_wrapper, options);
});
```

```js
/*angular.json*/

{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "minimus-master": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/minimus-master",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/vendors/jquery/jquery.min.js",
              "src/assets/vendors/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.js",
              "src/assets/vendors/isotope-layout/isotope.pkgd.js",
              "src/assets/vendors/jquery-one-page/jquery.nav.min.js",
              "src/assets/vendors/jquery.easing/jquery.easing.min.js",
              "src/assets/vendors/jquery.matchHeight/jquery.matchHeight.min.js",
              "src/assets/vendors/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js",
              "src/assets/vendors/masonry-layout/masonry.pkgd.js",
              "src/assets/vendors/jquery.waypoints/jquery.waypoints.min.js",
              "src/assets/vendors/swiper/swiper.jquery.js",
              "src/assets/vendors/menu/menu.js",
              "src/assets/vendors/typed/typed.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/main.js"            
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "minimus-master:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "minimus-master:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "minimus-master:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "minimus-master-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "minimus-master:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "minimus-master:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "minimus-master"
}
```

Comment: We have no idea what "not working" means. It's also a mystery to me what you would be trying to accomplish by pouring old jQuery wine into new Angular bottles. If you continue down this path, figuring out why scripts aren't loading will be the least of your problems. I suggest throwing away the old app and rewriting it in Angular, salvaging whatever code snippets or utilities you can. By the way, you should learn the names of the tools you are using. There is no such thing as "AngularJS5". "AngularJS" is an old framework. I suppose you mean "Angular".

Comment: What does "not working" mean? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Does `ng serve` produce build output or does that report that it can't find the files?

Comment: Not working in terms of jquery code. for example
/**
   * Typing effect
   */
jQuery('.typing__module').each(function (index) {
 var self = jQuery(this),
      _wrapper = jQuery('.typed', self)[0],
      optData = eval('(' + self.attr('data-options') + ')'),
      optDefault = {
  stringsElement: self.find('.typed-strings')[0],
  typeSpeed: 50,
  backSpeed: 500,
  fadeOut: true,
  loop: true
 },
      options = jQuery.extend(optDefault, optData);
 var typed = new Typed(_wrapper, options);
});

Comment: Add the erros that you get to the question.

Comment: I am not getting any errors while "ng serve" .
But see the jquery files I included is that correct ?
As I am converting HTML template to angular version so I have to include that all.

Comment: adding jquery code inside main.ts is not correct. Try to separate them by components

Comment: @OmurbekKadyrbekov I am not adding jquery in main.ts Please check my main.js file which is mentioned in angulat.json file so you will get idea.

Comment: oh, sorry. I would say adding custom js file is poor design in angular

Comment: @OmurbekKadyrbekov what to do when converting custom designed HTML to angular js template ?

Comment: @RonakChauhan is there any demo for your html template project?

Comment: I am using this template.
https://themewagon.com/themes/free-responsive-personal-portfolio-template-download/

Comment: what does this line do: var typed = new Typed(_wrapper, options); does _wrapper make the word go to the next line when there's no more space?

Answer (score 0):

> Declare **Jquery**

In your component typecript file, declare jquery outside of the component class

After imports, before @Component decorator

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
```

And then inside the component class, use

```
$('.typing__module').each(function (index) {
    var self = $(this),
            _wrapper = $('.typed', self)[0],
            optData = eval('(' + self.attr('data-options') + ')'),
            optDefault = {
        stringsElement: self.find('.typed-strings')[0],
        typeSpeed: 50,
        backSpeed: 500,
        fadeOut: true,
        loop: true
    },
            options = $.extend(optDefault, optData);
    var typed = new Typed(_wrapper, options);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare Jquery,

`import * as $ from 'jquery';` Also import Typed
`import * as Typed from 'typed.js'`

If they are installed via npm or yarn, you should be okay without adding to angular.json.

Then you should be able to correctly reference both without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can load html templates main.js i.e. **src/assets/js/main.js** at the end of all compiled js files by Angular

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<!--All Code here-->
</div>
<script src="~/dist/Infotech/runtime.js"></script>
<script src="~/dist/Infotech/polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="~/dist/Infotech/styles.js"></script>
<script src="~/dist/Infotech/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="~/dist/Infotech/main.js"></script>
**<script src="~/src/assets/js/main.js"></script>**
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this might help :)