# Angular - How to reference an external javascript file at build time?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular9

After I build my angular app, I have to perform one last manual step to get my program to run: The platform it runs on has a requirement that its javascript file is in the `<head>` of the html file that is running. Their .js is on a CDN. So basically, post-build, I have to open up `index.html` and add the following:

```
<script src="https://cdn.fragilecorp.com/lib/js/platform.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Is there a way I can accomplish this automatically using angular configs or a different way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in `.angular-cli.json` (`.angular.json` in older versions), I believe you can add what's inside of `src` to the `scripts` array.

Check this out:

[How to include external JS file to angular5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51205537/how-to-include-external-js-file-to-angular5)

Comment: That works for local files, but this one has to be referenced directly from the CDN. Can't reference a url in the `scripts` array.

Comment: OK my bad , check out the second answer here. To do it completely dynamic, you can read environments file to make sure you are in production mode to load it dynamically. httpss://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489916/how-to-load-external-scripts-dynamically-in-angular/42766146#42766146